# How to get the text/time of the notification pushed from Parse?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, apple-push-notifications

I push notifications to my own app from Parse, and my app can receive the notifications well. What I’m trying to do now is to get the notification text/message, and the time when the notification arrives. I try to implement a notification history for my app (similar to Notification Center). Please show me where to start for making this function in Xcode, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a property to the Push Notification using a custom JSON payload:

```
{
"alert":"Hello",
"sound":"default",
"pushDate":"dateformat"
}
```